# Interpolation within @mixin-name for dynamic @include

Tags: sass

I want to dynamicaly `@include` other `@mixins` in a `@mixin`.

But it seems like `@include` can't accept a variable as a `@mixin-name`,
is there any trick to do this?

**Here is situation:**

```
@mixin foo($_Value){
  @include #{$_Value}
}

@mixin bar(){...}

@mixin baz(){...}
```

---

I want to be able to use `@include A(B)` or `@include A(C)`, to include `B` or `C` additionally.

I have a second solution, but that's not the answer I am mainly looking for. I want to explicitly know, if there's any trick to use some sort of interpolation within `@mixin-names`.

```
@mixin foo($_Value...){
  @if (length($_Value) > 0) {
    @if (index($_Value, bar)) { @include bar }
    @if (index($_Value, baz)) { @include baz }
  }
}

@mixin bar(){...}

@mixin baz(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Interpolation within `@function` or `@mixin` name is not supported.

You can't. As well as `@functions` `@mixins`  don't support [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) (yet).

This is indeed the best way to achieve what you want.

```
@mixin A($_Value...){
  @if (length($_Value) > 0) {
    @if (index($_Value, B)) { @include B }
    @if (index($_Value, C)) { @include C }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately there is none.

Comment: I have a new solution

Answer (score 0):

I work with a trick to solve this situation.

```
@mixin foo($_Value...){
  @if (length($_Value) > 0) {
    @each $_ThisValue in $_Value{
      @extend .#{$_ThisValue}
    }
  }
}

@mixin bar(){...}

@mixin baz(){...}

.bar{
  @include bar;
}

.baz{
  @include baz;
}
```

mixin with extend to do this trick
and it also can do with class or limited $_ThisValue